# Azure Functions with python runtime. H2O Module not available error

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, h2o

I am trying to create an Azure python function which uses H20 module. When I tried to test it locally I am getting module not available error even though I have specified it in requirements.txt and it seem to be installed in the virtual env and I am able to run using virtual environment manually.

**Minimal Python code:**

```
import datetime
import logging

import h2o
import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**requirement.txt**

```
h2o==3.32.0.2
```

**Error.txt:**
[image]

Python version 3.9m Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Created the Azure Python Timer Trigger Function in VS Code.
2. Installed the below dependencies in the VS Code Project terminal:

```
pip install requests
pip install tabulate
pip install future
```

3. If any existing or previous versions of H2o is available, uninstall it using the below command:
   [image]
4. Next, run this command to install H2o module in the Project integrated terminal:

```py
pip install -f http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_Py.html h2o
```

[image]

With the version of `h2o==3.32.0.2`, I also got the same exceptions in VS Code output terminal.
So, I have tried with the below versions and working well.

**requirements.txt file**:

```
azure-functions
h2o==3.36.1.2
```

**Result**:

[image]

It also working with the version [`3.14.0.2` H2o module in Python](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-weierstrass/2/index.html).

Comment: I have selected this has answered because it ran in local but still the issue exists in Azure Function. When I tried to run it as a Azure function it fails with no logs. Can you try it in a function?

Comment: In Azure Portal Function App, you're asking? If yes, could you please raise a new thread so that I'll try assisting separately for getting that fix on portal function app!

Comment: Yes. Are you asking me to create a new question Stack Overflow?.

Comment: Yes @The6thSense

Comment: Okay will do the same

Comment: I have posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72983886/azure-functions-with-python-runtime-h2o-module-not-available-error-in-azure-por

Comment: Thanks @The6thSense, I'll look into the issue in Portal also and get back to you in that post!