# Azure Functions with python runtime. H2O Module not available error in Azure portal

Tags: python, azure-functions

This is related to my previous question. [Azure Functions with python runtime. H2O Module not available error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72888069/azure-functions-with-python-runtime-h2o-module-not-available-error).
Due to the help from fellow SO I was able to solve the issue. But when I tried to deploy the source in Azure function I faced issue when imposing H2O.

**Function Configuration:**

```
[ 
  {
    "name": "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "python",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

**Python Code:**

```
import datetime
import logging

import h2o
import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm looking into this issue, facing lot of errors while running in the Azure Portal, I'm trying to figure out the errors!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MTThanks I am also validating from my ends. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT for now I have created a batch service instead of Function. Wanted to keep you updated.

Comment: Hello @The6thSense, please follow the updates here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/96516